# jsp:include param array

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I would like to pass an array as a parameter in a `jsp:include`. Code below does not work:

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="stylesheets" value="login.css" />
    <jsp:param name="stylesheets" value="login2.css" />
</jsp:include>
```

What is the right way to do this, so that `${param.stylesheets} = "login.css, login2.css"`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to access it by `${paramValues.stylesheets}` instead. It returns a `String[]`.

Comment: You deserve the highest of fives.

Comment: Be aware that user can append "?stylesheets=http://badserver.com/somethingbad.css" and someone, who uses this link, could see altered page which could lead to security vulnerability. And if you include javascript files this way, it could be much worse.